# Consider the following expression about natural number: \forall n\exists m: m^{2}=n .

Tags: education

$$ \forall n\exists m: m^{2}=n $$
How do I interpret this? This is part of my assignment question but I cant carry on without understanding this.

Comment: This means: every natural number is a perfect square. $2$ is the smallest counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a natural number, the expression $n=m^2$ for some $n$ tells us that every natural number can be expressed as a product of a real number $m$ to itself. To see this note that:

$0=0^2$

$1=1^2$

$2=(\sqrt{2})^2$
Etc.

Bear in mind that $m$ is not necessary an integer.

It also works even if $n$ is a real number.

Comment: It also works if $n$ is just a real number.

We'll have another real $m$ that satisfies the relation proposed.

Example: $\pi=(\sqrt{\pi})^2$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas yes it is :-). I put it as a note. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

To make your statement complete
(where 
"$\mathbb{N}$"
indicates the natural numbers):

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} 
\ \exists m \in \mathbb{N}
\mid m^{2}=n
$.

This is false,
because $2$
is a counterexample.

To test your understanding:

Is this true or false?

$\forall m \in \mathbb{N} 
\ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}
\mid m^{2}=n
$.

Comment: I take it that it's a negation of ∀n∃m:m^2=n so it's true.
is that correct?

Comment: It's not a negation; but it is true. My "|" means "such that", the same as your ":".